# Handlebars custom helper returning value

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('indexcheck', (value, test, options)=>{
    if (value < test){
        return options.fn(this);
    }else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
})
```

```
    {{#each [Time Series (Daily)]}}
        {{#indexcheck @index 5}}
            <h2>{{@key}}</h2>
            <p>test: {{[1. open]}}</p>
            <p>{{[2. high]}}</p>
        {{/indexcheck}}
    {{/each}}
```

```
OUTPUT

2020-02-21
test:

2020-02-20
test:

2020-02-19
test:

2020-02-18
test:

2020-02-14
test:
```

I found above custom helper on SWAG helper, and it works fine with displaying only 5 @keys as expected.
However, it wouldn't display those p tags (1. open, 2. high) values.

I've done some troubleshooting, and it seems like it's because of the return statement, maybe it's only returning 'value', but not all the data from json?

How could I fix this problem? I'd want to display only specific number of objects with its key and values inside.